# NoMethodError: undefined method `setup' for Devise:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

### Environment

- Ruby **[1.9.3p547]**
- Rails **[3.2.22.5]**
- Devise **[3.0.4]**

### Current behavior

When i try to run any rake or rails command, i am getting below error

> rake aborted!
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `setup' for Devise:Module
>   /home/tatva/sites/Quotiful-API-master/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in`'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in`each'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
>   /home/tatva/sites/Quotiful-API-master/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`require_environment!'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/gems/rake-12.2.1/exe/rake:27:in`'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
>   /home/tatva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@quotiful/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

### Expected behavior

Why i am getting this error. is this version issue of devise? I don't want to upgrade devise version as it will effect whole project.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, that version of Devise is 6 years old. Also, that version of Rails is 3 years old. You undoubtedly will have a myriad of security vulnerabilities on your application. Out of interest, why are you against upgrading to up-to-date versions (other than the work involved)?

Comment: @Jon Because its not my own project, its client's project so that's why i don't want to make any change :). and ruby version is also 6 years old . :D which is not more maintain by community since last 2 years :)

Comment: You should recommend to your client that they get you to update it.

Comment: @Jon I updated the version of devise to 3.5. but still getting same error